# Joomla 3.x, styling pop up message

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, joomla3.0

I am new to Joomla, I need to build a simple page that contains logos, when clicking any of the logos I need to see pop up message with description of the logo I clicked, close button should also be included.

Comment: If you are doing Joomla development, please join us at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap for this.

In your template you should include jQuery and Bootstrap 4. You can do it by adding in your */templates/your_theme/index.php* the following:

```
<?php
$doc->addScript('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.min.js', 'text/javascript');
$doc->addScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js', 'text/javascript');
$doc->addStyleSheet('https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
$doc->addScript('https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js', 'text/javascript');
?>
```

Then you can use simple Boorstrap 4 modal, like this

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<div class="your-any-logo-class" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Put your logo here
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Modal description
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

More about Bootstrap 4 modal here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#live-demo